# Validate serializer object without the field need for validation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a following viewset,

```
class VoteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = VoteSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Vote.objects.filter(created_by=self.request.user)
```

serializer

```
class VoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Vote
        fields = ('id', 'request')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

and model.

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='votes')
    request = models.ForeignKey(Request, related_name='votes')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [('request', 'created_by')]
```

I am trying to save user's vote but I get `IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed` when I post a vote for the same request twice. I can fix the error by adding `created_by` to `VoteSerializer` however I don't want to have it in my serialized data. What are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try [object-level-validation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation)

```
class VoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Vote
        fields = ('id', 'request')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)

    def validate(self, data):
        """
        Check Unique vote per user.
        """
        created_by = self.context['request'].user
        if self.instance is None:
            Vote(**data, created_by=created_by).full_clean()
        else:
            self.instance.created_by = created_by
            self.instance.full_clean()
        return data
```

Comment: Thanks, this would probably work. However I don't like that now we have the validation on 2 different places. Once in the model (unique_together) and in the serializer.

Comment: in the model you have rule for save, in the serializer you have data validation it is not the same.

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked, but instead of manually validation that condition I used `Vote(**data, created_by=created_by).full_clean()` .

Comment: glad to help!, you can edit my answer or create youself it can help other who will find the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueTogetherValidator

class ExampleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # ...
    class Meta:
        # ToDo items belong to a parent list, and have an ordering defined
        # by the 'position' field. No two items in a given list may share
        # the same position.
        validators = [
            UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=ToDoItem.objects.all(),
                fields=('list', 'position')
            )
        ]
```

[UniqueTogetherValidator](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#uniquetogethervalidator)